# Type error creating R gate in Q#?

Tags: quantum-gate, programming, q#

The R operation in Q# is listed by Microsoft in the documentation as follows

`operation R (pauli : Pauli, theta : Double, qubit : Qubit) : Unit`

However, when I try to use the following command in a Q# operation,

`R(PauliX,0,Q1);`

I get an error, referencing the line of code for the R command:

`The type of the given argument does not match the expected type.`

Q1 is of course a Qubit, so I don't see what could be causing the problem. I've also been having difficulty getting the R1 gate working, but I suspect for similar reasons.

To see the relevant documentation, please visit [R operation, Q# Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/qsharp/api/qsharp/microsoft.quantum.intrinsic.r).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument `theta` has to be a `Double`, and 0 is a constant of type `Int`. Q# doesn't have implicit type casting, so you need to make sure your second argument is a `Double`. If you're looking for a rotation by zero angle, you'll need to do `R(PauliX, 0.0, Q1);`. Alternatively, you can use `ToDouble` to cast an integer parameter to a `Double`.

Comment: This also fixes the issues I was having with other gates like R1 in case anyone viewing this is wondering.